Looking for a quote conveying relation between answerer and asker of a question
Note: This is not one of those  "I recall reading something like this, but where?"-questions. Instead, I have no idea if something matching my specific wishes exists to begin with. Thus on the other hand, several good approximations may exist, but I hope this does not turn this into a big list question or make it off-topic for this forum.
Suppose person A asks a question and person B answers it. I would like to find a quote that expresses something about the relation between the two, something like

As reverence, B was eager to match language and style of A (as in: You meet Shakespeare lost in the city, he asks where the train station is, and you answer in the form of  sonnet).
Or: The way B formulates their answer tells us that the question was asked by A
Or: From B's answer, we learn a lot about person A
or something in that direction

Bonus points if the quote is (a) mildly humorous and/or (b) science-related.

Sorry, but this kind of recommendation request is the kind of "big list" question that's considered off-topic for this site. Recommendation requests and open-ended lists have long been deemed off-topic here because they tend to spawn long lists of low-quality answers none of which is more correct than any other.
